# Account Query Exception - Fail to retrieve account for contract.code

Tags: nodeos

I have started my nodeos and deployed some contracts and pushed some actions. Something went wrong and I removed the local/share/eosio director.

Now, when starting nodeos again, I get the following error:

```
Account Query Exception
Fail to retrieve account for contract.code
```

What does it mean? How to get rid of it again?

contract.code was an account name of a contract that I have deployed before. Why does nodeos still know about it?

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that the nodeos was replaying the contract that uses `contract.code`. As this account was not defined it failed.

Not sure about the details though.